# Execução não encontra 'org.junit.Assert' mesmo tendo o jar do JUnit no classpath

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, maven, junit

Estou com um problema do qual já pesquisei muito e ainda não encontrei a resposta. Tenho um caso de teste do qual estou tentando executar e mandar uma mensagem para o console. Mas mesmo tendo as jars do JUnit, ele acusa como se não encontrasse-as. Estou com um projeto maven configurado com spring no meu eclipse, e já adicionei a biblioteca do JUnit ao classpath. Adicionei manualmente indo ao Build Path, e também coloquei a dependência no POM.
Dentro de maven dependencies tem outra jar do JUnit, versão 3.8.1.

Pensei ser conflito de versões entre a versão especificada no POM (Está 3.8.1) e a que adicionei manualmente (4). Mas não é isso. Já tentei colocar versão 4 no POM e não funcionou, já tentei deixar só a que coloquei manual, ou só a da dependência e também não funcionou. E tenho outro projeto menor, também maven mas sem spring que está funcionando normalmente, com as mesmas jars do JUnit. Quando tento executar um caso de teste, esse é o erro que vem ao console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/javaliproject] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at br.ufc.quixada.javaliproject.evaluationservice.teste.test(teste.java:17)
        at br.ufc.quixada.javaliproject.controller.RunnerController.run(RunnerController.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

É como se os jars do JUnit não estivessem adicionados, mas eles estão. Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

A classe de teste que eu havia criado era essa:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.Test;






public class Runner {
    @Test
    public static String runClass() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        int retornoEsperado = 9;
        int retornoFeito = 10;

        String assertionError = null;
        try {

            assertEquals(retornoEsperado, retornoFeito);
            System.out.println("O método está correto");
        }
        catch (AssertionError ae) {
            assertionError = ae.toString();
            System.out.println(assertionError);
        }

        return "Executou!"; 



    }



}
```

Aqui está o pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>javali</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaliproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
        <finalName>javaliproject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->

        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <javax.activation.version>1.1.1</javax.activation.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.0-alpha-1</javax.servlet.version>
        <javaee.web.api.version>6.0</javaee.web.api.version>
        <java.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</java.validation.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>

        <!-- Database access -->
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1204-jdbc42</postgresql.version>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <spring.security.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${java.validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Databases - Uses POSTGRESQL by default -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons File Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.xeustechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-core</artifactId> 
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>


    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Comment: O que ocorre se você executar `mvn test`?

Comment: Posta teu pom.xml

Comment: @LeonardoVillela, postei o pom

Comment: Essa arquivo de teste está no diretório src/test/java?

Comment: Consegui ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a solução no StackOverFlow em inglês. Apenas removi a tag de escopo da dependencia do JUnit no meu pom, onde tinha `<scope>test</scope>`. Segue o link para a resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156332/tomcat-doesnt-find-org-junit-assert-even-though-i-have-junit-jars-in-my-class

Answer (score 1):

Olá, o primeiro problema que vejo é que métodos de teste do Junit devem ter o tipo do retorno `void` e o método não pode ser static, também modifiquei seu pom.xml para adicionar a versão correta do junit e o modulo de testes do spring, provavelmente você vai precisar, segue o arquivo pom.xml, apos adiciona-lo em seu projeto rode os seguintes comandos:

1. `mvn clean`
2. `mvn install`

Segue no gist, por que não consegui formatar aqui: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e25788a35c8890a14c9363444a1bd63

Segue a classe de teste:

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Runner {
    @Test
    public void runClass() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        int retornoEsperado = 9;
        int retornoFeito = 10;

        String assertionError = null;
        try {

            assertEquals(retornoEsperado, retornoFeito);
            System.out.println("O método está correto");
        }
        catch (AssertionError ae) {
            assertionError = ae.toString();
            System.out.println(assertionError);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, Leonardo. Obrigado, mas infelizmente isso não funcionou. Continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Você substituiu o seu pom pelo o que eu coloquei no gist? por que na minha maquina funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim, eu substituí o pom, e continuou dando o mesmo erro. Mas encontrei uma solução no StackOverFlow em inglês. Agradeço pela ajuda, de toda forma